# filtering array based on key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array in the below format which I need to filter based on the key and value. I am planning to use Underscore.js for this. I tried using the following code but it searches for all the fields value but I need to search based on the key and value and not in all the keys. How to use Underscore for this?

Please let me know.

```
var sortedArray = _.sortBy(_.filter(arr, function (obj) {
                      return _.values(obj).some(function (el) {
                          return (typeof el ==="string" && el.match(new RegExp(searchStr, "i")));
                       });
                      }), function (obj){
                            return obj[colName];
                    });
}


{
  "recordsTotal": 5,
  "recordsFiltered": 5,
  "aaData": [
  {
    "firstname": "Pradeep",
    "lastname": "Kumar",
    "city": "Bangalore",
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Wells",
    "city": "Calcutta",
    "country": "India"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Praveen",
    "lastname": "Garg",
    "city": "columbo",
    "country": "Srilanka"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Joe",
    "lastname": "Wells",
    "city": "Luton",
    "country": "UK"
  },
  {
    "firstname": "Rita",
    "lastname": "Wahlin",
    "city": "houston",
    "country": "USA"
   }
 ] 
}
```

Comment: Please show the sample input and expected output clearly

Comment: Please get the code at least to a point where it can be parsed?

Comment: can't understand what you want without proper inputs and output expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I was not able to post the question properly. I found a solution and the is using the below code.

```
    var searchColData=function(arr, searchStr, colName){
       var sortedArray = _.filter(arr, function (obj) {
                       return (_.property(colName)(obj).toString().match(new RegExp(searchStr, "i")));
                      });

    return sortedArray;

}
```

Hope this helps someone.